# How can I create a jitter plot with 27.000 lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have a CSV file with 27.000 lines. I am trying to create a jitter plot, just like this one [https://static1.squarespace.com/static/56fd706140261df95349d4bd/t/59297c72579fb3d813d591c1/1495891103667/Jitter+Example+The+Truthful+Art.png?format=1000w].

[image]

The 'y' axis would be the column called "VALOR_REEMBOLSADO" (stands for "refund value"). The 'x' axis would be the column called "MES" (stands for "month").

It represents the spending of brazilian senators in 2017. The CSV file is very organized, but originally has the "VALOR_REEMBOLSADO" as string and not as float. I replaced the "," for ".", but I still can't plot the chart.

Can someone help me with the code? What code can create a chart like that?

Here you find the CSV file of the year 2017: https://www12.senado.leg.br/transparencia/dados-abertos-transparencia/dados-abertos-ceaps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I have to admit that I cannot understand some aspects of your question (first link doesn't work, and even more important: you want an x-axis which shows the months but in the plot, the data is shown over states).

But I see that your problems start already at the very beginning of reading the data in, so I'll try to give you the needed hints to start:

For reading in csv-data like this, I'd recommend `pandas`, usually imported with

```
import pandas as pd
```

It has a csv reader included, which is quite powerful. Generally, you should avoid manually tweaking the data sources you have (like changing decimal signs etc.), because this is something which is already adressed by importer functions like `read_csv` (and you don't want to do this again and again in the future with new data files but the same plot generation):

```
filepath = 'wherever/file/may/roam/2017.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(filepath, skiprows=1, sep=';', usecols=[1, 9], decimal=',')
```

With `filepath` you tell the importer where you stored the csv-file, `skiprows=1` says that you're not interested in the first line of the file, `sep` defines the delimiter between the columns and via `usecols` you can pick only the columns of interest, 'MES' and 'VALOR_REEMBOLSADO' in your example.
`decimal` specifies the decimal sign of float numbers in your data.

Now `data` contains a pandas dataframe of your data:

```
In: data[:10]
Out:
   MES  VALOR_REEMBOLSADO
0    1              97.00
1    1            6000.00
2    1             418.04
3    1            1958.95
4    1            1178.67
5    1            1252.65
6    2              62.30
7    2             240.81
8    2            6000.00
9    2            2062.25
```

So this should be already something you can play around with.

This data can now be plotted with `matplotlib` or `seaborn` if you like.
`pandas` itself has also some plotting methods already included.

However, your question differs from the example plot you added, as I pointed out, so from this point on it's a little difficult to help precisely your needs.

You can aggregate all equal months for example, to create a plot over months. For those cases there is a `groupby` method for Dataframes:

```
data.groupby('MES')
```

This only returns a so called grouby-object, but you can tell it, what you want to do with the grouped data, e.g.:

```
In: data.groupby('MES').sum()
Out: 
     VALOR_REEMBOLSADO
MES                   
1           1558581.11
2           1951731.07
3           2225328.21
4           2248882.83
5           2256224.68
6           2216981.94
7           2053173.90
8           2372847.10
9           2161915.35
10          2355417.34
11          2294658.51
12          2938033.00
```

if you are interested in the sum within each month. The same for the average with `data.groupby('MES').mean()`. And for a first plot you could just add the plotting method like

```
data.groupby('MES').sum().plot()
```

which produces

[image]

If you want to see the distribution and the mean value like in the picture in your question (but still plotted over months, not over states, because I don't see this information in your file) you could have a look at scatter plots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(data['MES'],data['VALOR_REEMBOLSADO'])
plt.plot(data.groupby('MES').mean()['VALOR_REEMBOLSADO'], 'k_', ms=10)
```

which produces

[image]

But as you mention seaborn in your tag list: this library provides a jitter plot like the on you reference to via `stripplot`. So this is finally the answer to the plotting part of your question, leading to this piece of code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
filepath = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gabrielacaesar/studyingPython/master/ceap-sf-new-12-04-2018.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(filepath, usecols=[1,9], decimal=',')
x = data['MES'].values
y = data['VALOR_REEMBOLSADO'].values
sns.stripplot(x, y, jitter=True)
```

which produces
[image]

Comment: I uploaded the CSV on the following link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gabrielacaesar/studyingPython/master/ceap-sf-new-12-04-2018.csv

Comment: When read exactly how you told me, filepath = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gabrielacaesar/studyingPython/master/ceap-sf-new-12-04-2018.csv', it still doesn't recognize the dataset. Later it says it could not find the file.. Or that "'str' object has no attribute 'head'", for example. :( Thank you for the help

Comment: The structure of the file you uploaded to githubusercontent.com is different to those files you referred to in your question. This file would need an importer like `data = pd.read_csv(filepath, usecols=[1, 9], decimal=',')`